# OrientDB geolocation

Tags: geolocation, orientdb, nosql

I´m using the OrientDB for NoSQL database, and i dont know how to query in geolocation exactly. I´ve read the specific documentation:

[OrientDB Functions](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/wiki/SQL-Where#bundled-functions)

but does not understand the significance of the values.

The distance function:

> distance() - Computes the distance between two points in the globe using the Haversine algorithm. Coordinates must be as degrees

Example:

> where distance(x, y,52.20472, 0.14056) <= 30

Two questions:

1. What is the X, Y, and the 30 values?
2. Are the values (52.20472, 0.14056) latitude and longitude?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

distance(x, y,52.20472, 0.14056) <= 30

x and y are the longitude and latitude (variables) respectively of the record/position which you are calculating distance from the fixed coordinates 52.20472, 0.14056.

consider another example:

select distance(longitude, latitude, 52.20472, 0.14056) <= 30 as distance from Places order by distance

This query will loop through the records in the Places Class/Cluster and for each record it injects the longitude and latitude of the record and calculate it's distance to the fixed position (52.20472, 0.14056) and return the places that are within 30m.

where

Places is a class/cluster which contains records of places
longitude is the longitude field of the current record
latitude is the latitude field of the current record
distance is an alias for the field name

Comment: Hi @andresmafra, Thanks for the point. I'm not very sure but I think it's in metres because when working with angles in degrees the unit of distance is usually in metres or kilometres. I googled the Harvesine Algorithm and it seems the distance is in Kilometres.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [this](http://www.orientechnologies.com/active-user-community/#!msg/orient-database/7EE_tDw8IhM/aCNzwXBLwxcJ) group and answered by @Opeoluwa, the distance is in Kilometers!

Comment: This can easily be verified by using OrientDB to evaluate `select distance(0,0,0,90)`. The result is approx. 10007 .... and we know that the distance from the equator to the North Pole is about 10,000 km.

Answer (score 0):

Basically that is just an example of the usage. And it is just showing on how you could select items which are as close or closer than 30 from the position (52.20472, 0.14056) expressed as degreees.

If I understood right then the X & Y should be the name of the position values with the items.

Comment: But the 30 can be considered 30 miles, or 30 kilometers? I didnt understand the degrees...

Comment: Location things explained in wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system And for the units used, I suppose the service provider should be specifying on what is actually used.