# Expanded example using distance() function

Tags: orientdb

**Note**, I'm aware of [OrientDB geolocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032138/orientdb-geolocation) (though I have some trouble with the poor formatting of the accepted answer, as it makes huge assumptions and in fact may be syntactically incorrect, but cannot yet submit edits).

I have a Vertex of `Bank` with a property of `latLong` as a comma-delimited string. I'm having some trouble using the provided `distance()` function with OrientDB. Since `distance(x,y,lat,long)` is expecting discrete values we wrote a split function that returns the latLong as an array:

```
{ ..., values: [xx.xxx,yy.yyy], ... }
```

However, I (we) can't seem to make either the provided answer or the document example to work. I suspect the answer is simple and we're over thinking it, but we're stuck.

### `split(input,delimiter)`

```
return input.split(delimiter)`
```

Pretty simple really.

### What's wrong in the original question?

In the cited question above, the query

```
select distance(x,y,originx,originy) <= 30 as distance from Bank order by distance
```

generates the below error

```
com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error on parsing command at position #0: Error parsing query: select distance(x,y,originx,originy) <= 30 as distance from Bank Encountered " "<=" "<= ""
```

and should be

```
select distance(x,y,lat,long) as distance from Bank where distance <= 30 order by distance;
```

which returns nothing.

If Bank were to have discrete properties for lat and long, how are they passed to distance()? Specifically, is OrientDB expecting specific property names?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

You have to insert in Bank the properties lat and long like double